# Is there any tabs mechanism for xtermjs?

Tags: xtermjs

## Feature Question

I was about to write some tab mechanism for my **xtermjs** terminal when I suddenly found this `tabindex="0"` attribute on **xterm** element:

```html
<div dir="ltr" class="terminal xterm" tabindex="0">...</div>
```

Are there any plans to add or is there already any mechanism to add **xtermjs** tabs support? I couldn't find anything on that in docs.

Comment: Can you specify, what you mean by "tab mechanism"? The tabindex attribute is meant to make an HTML focusable by tabbing, thus enables xterm.js to receive the focus, which is what most ppl want in a mainly keyboard driven env. If you mean tab mechanism is a sense of several stacked xterm.js outputs - nope thats def. not planned. For that you'd need multiple terminal instances, xterm.js only delivers the abstraction for one instance.

Comment: Thank you Jerch, please copy your comment to an answer so I can approve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tabindex attribute is meant to make an HTML element focusable by tabbing, thus enables xterm.js to receive the focus, which is what most ppl want in a mainly keyboard driven env.

If you mean tab mechanism is a sense of several stacked xterm.js outputs - nope thats def. not planned. For that you'd need multiple terminal instances, xterm.js only delivers the abstraction for one instance.